# How to forcefullly set Activated = false for a particular item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am little bit confused how to explain this. Let me try.

I implemented a Nav Drawer. I implemented highlighted background for selected item by using state_activated in selector.

**MENU_SELECTOR:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_active" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_active" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_normal" />
</selector>
```

But I want 3rd item in the drawer will remain with normal background all the time. So, is it possible to exclude only 3rd item from this menu_selector?

Below is my code for drawer

```
public void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new BookListFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            openCredit(); // THIS WILL JUST OPEN A DIALOG, HENCE I DON'T WANT IT TO KEEP HIGHLIGHTED BACKGROUND
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "frag_"+position).commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer);
        }
    }
```

LISTVIEW XML

```
<ListView
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_selector" />
```

Comment: The better solution is to remove the third item from the drawer entirely. IMHO, a navigation drawer entry should not be opening a dialog.

Comment: yaa, I am also planning to do so ... just checking before whether that is possible or not :) . thanks